# how many maximum concurrent users can a tomcat instance, jboss instance and weblogic instance handle?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jboss, weblogic

I am willing to launch a web application. It was completely on the structs only and no springs are used in it. We are willing to launch in either tomcat or jboss or weblogic application servers.

So, I may get many users' hits to the application. My hardware is 32GB/8cores and the OS is RHEL6.3. So, I would like to know how many maximum concurrent users can a tomcat instance handle. Similar the way, I would like to know about the maximum concurrent users that jboss-as and weblogic also handle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you considered measuring the figures and doing some load testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not structs, it's "Struts" and no springs but "Spring". Although you have provided your hardware configuration, I would strongly suggest you to use JMeter to do the load testing of your application in your production environment before going live. That would give you a better picture rather than calculating on theories. Look here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-jmeter-to-perform-load-testing-on-a-web-server

Comment: Sorry Java Lovers for typing the spellings in wrong without knowledge concentrating only on app server related things. And thank you Aakash for correcting me. I shall be careful further. And I shall check out the load using Jmeter. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between servlet container and the application server is that application server provides API to make possible or simplify certain tasks.

If your application is self-sufficient I would recommend going for Tomcat as JBoss is much more resource intensive as well as Weblogic, moreover Weblogic costs some money.

In regards to how you can load test your application, there are following good free and open source tools available:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide which highlights main features of the tools and has simple sample load test followed by features and limitations comparison matrix and load reports for the same scenario. Personally I agree with Aakash and would choose JMeter, however your view may be different.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. I shall check different tools and choose the better.